# How can i extract a word from the middle of a cell, in MySql?

Tags: ssms

I want to extract the word with the version in another new table, for example: "fruit 2.0" from the second table, from every cell. How can I do that? Example of database below:

```
select * from mytable where mytab like'%fruit%'.    

 User   MyTab
    1   ["{myfruit":"apple","store":"mystore","username"andy",\\; fruit 2.0 \\,"mysstore is null=false":"133-aascd-ee54-678v"}"]
    2   ["{myfruit":"apple","store":"mystore","username"andy",\\; fruit 1.2 \\,"mysstore is null=false":"133-aascd-ee54-678v"}"]
    3   ["{myfruit":"apple&banana","store":"mystore","username"andy",\\; fruit 3.0 \\,"mysstore is null=false":"133-aascd-ee54-678v"}"]
    4   ["{myfruit":"apple&banana&pineaple","store":"mystore","username"andy",\\;fruit 1.0 \\,"mysstore is null=false":"133-aascd-ee54-678vsadsaafvvrrrv"}"]
```

The final result i want to have is:

```
User    MyTab2
   1    fruit 2.0
   2    fruit 1.2
   3    fruit 3.0
   4    fruit 1.0
```

Some column properties:

```
Data Type   varchar
System Type varchar
Length  8000
Collation   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
Numeric Precision   0
Numeric Scale   0
Is sparse   FALSE
Is Column Set   FALSE
Statistical Semantics   FALSE
Not for Replication FALSE
ANSI Padding Status TRUE
Full Text   FALSE
```

Comment: Please format your question properly!

Comment: Is your column `MyTab` in json format?

Comment: Yes, the format is JSON. @James

Comment: @NJInamdar sorry, but i'm a beginner in sql querry and also it's my first post here.

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL? can you please share the table structure?

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL Server management Studio. I put some column properties in the question

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MSSQL ?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a `MSSQL` solution over here. It's very contrived (and may be inefficient) and I feel you should fetch the columns from the database and then try to extract the text using regex.

```
    SELECT id, SUBSTRING(
      mytab, 
      PATINDEX('%fruit [0-9\.]%', mytab), 
      PATINDEX('%\\,%', mytab)-PATINDEX('%fruit [0-9\.]%', mytab) FROM mytable;
```

Basically, what I am doing here is

- Let `X` = `All 'fruit' occurences followed by a floating number (version)` found using [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- Let `Y` = Position of `\\,` which is sequence immediately after the string in the data samples you have shared
- I use the `SUBSTRING` function of MSSQL to extract the substring from the position 
   `SUBSTRING(mytab, X, Y-X)`

[Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/71e3a/32)